# Windows Azure: Can't see trace listener's output in diagnostics logs

Tags: .net, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-diagnostics

i want to log some messages using trace listeners in windows azure diagnostics. I am able to see the blob that diagnostics created on my permanent storage but i can't see the trace listener's output.

Here is my attempt in the worker role onStart method:

```
            var config = DiagnosticMonitor.GetDefaultInitialConfiguration();
            config.Logs.ScheduledTransferPeriod = System.TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1.0); 
            DiagnosticMonitor.Start("Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Diagnostics.ConnectionString", config);
            System.Diagnostics.Trace.Listeners.Add(new Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.DiagnosticMonitorTraceListener());
            System.Diagnostics.Trace.AutoFlush = true;
            System.Diagnostics.Trace.Write("some logging");
```

Comment: I answered a similar question a few days ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15672003/how-to-log-messages-to-the-windows-azure-storage/15673515#15673515. HTH.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're missing a buffer on your logs. If there is no buffer to read from, there will be nothing to transfer. Try adding something like:

```
config.OverallQuotaInMB = 4096;
config.Logs.BufferQuotaInMB = 512;
```

Your role's diagnostic blob (*found in wad-control-container*) content should look something like

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ConfigRequest xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <DataSources>
        <OverallQuotaInMB>4096</OverallQuotaInMB>
        <Logs>
            <BufferQuotaInMB>512</BufferQuotaInMB>
            <ScheduledTransferPeriodInMinutes>1</ScheduledTransferPeriodInMinutes>
            <ScheduledTransferLogLevelFilter>Information</ScheduledTransferLogLevelFilter>
        </Logs>
        ....
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a blog article specificaly for enabling trace in Workerroles. You find it here:
http://blog.amtopm.be/2014/07/20/azure-diagnostics-how-to-troubleshoot-your-code/

Let me know if you still have problems.